# Bootstrap Carousel doesn't change photo manually

Tags: html, carousel, bootstrap-5

I'm currently adding a Bootstrap carousel gallery into my page.

The photos change automatically after a few seconds, although if i try to change them manually, the buttons don't work.
I've added Jquery, PopperJs and Bootstrap, although i still can't make it to work properly.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <title>...</title>
        <meta name="description" content="..." />
        
        <!-- Favicon-->
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/favicon.ico" />
        <!-- Font Awesome icons (free version)-->
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.3.0/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Google fonts-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap)-->
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        
    </head>
    <body id="page-top">
        <!-- Navigation-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top"><img src="assets/img/logos/logo.png" alt="..."/></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    Menu
                    <i class="fas fa-bars ms-1"></i>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav text-uppercase ms-auto py-4 py-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#services">Services</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav text-uppercase ms-auto py-4 py-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item2"><a class="nav-link" href="/en/index.html" style="box-shadow: 0 1px #ffff;">EN</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
   
        </nav>
        <!-- Masthead-->
        <header class="masthead">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="masthead-subheading">...</div>
            <div class="masthead-heading">...</div>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase" href="#about">More Info</a>
            </div>
        </header>
                <!-- About-->
                <section class="page-section" id="about">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <h2 class="section-heading text-uppercase">About Us</h2>
                            <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted my-5"><p>...</h3>                    </div>
                </section>
                        <!--Gallery-->
                        <section class="page-section" id="gallery">
                        <div class="container">
                            <h2 class="section-heading text-uppercase text-center">Gallery</h2>
                            <div class="carousel slide carousel-fade my-5" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                                <div class="carousel-inner">
                                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                                        <img src="./assets/img/gallery/1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="carousel-item">
                                        <img src="./assets/img/gallery/2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="carousel-item">
                                        <img src="./assets/img/gallery/3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#gallery" data-bs-slide="prev">
                                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                                </button>
                                <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#gallery" data-bs-slide="next">
                                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>

        <!-- Services-->
        <section class="page-section" id="services">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading text-uppercase">Our Services</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="row text-center my-5">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                            <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                            <img class="logo" src="...">
                        </span>
                        <h4 class="my-3">...</h4>
                        <p class="text-muted">...</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!-- Contact-->
        <section class="page-section" id="contact">
            <div class="container">
                
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading text-uppercase">Contact Us</h2>
                    <h3 class="section-subheading text-white">...</h3>
                    <div class="row text-center"> 
                            <div class="col-md-4 column">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                                    <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                                    <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                </span>
                                <p class="contacts-text text-white">...</p>
                            </div>
            
                        <div class="col-md-4 column">
                            <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                                <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                                <i class="fas fa-phone fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                            </span>
                            <p class="contacts-text text-white">...</p>
                        </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                                    <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary "></i>
                                    <i class="fas fa-location-dot fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                    
                                </span>
                                <p class="contacts-text text-white">...</p>
                                <p class="contacts-text text-white">...</p>
                                <div class="google-map"><iframe src="..." width="400" height="300" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe></div>
                            </div> 
                    <p><h3 class="section-subheading text-white">...</h3></p>
                </div>

                <form id="contactForm" data-sb-form-api-token="API_TOKEN">
                    <div class="row align-items-stretch mb-5">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <!-- Name input-->
                                <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name *" data-sb-validations="required" />
                                <div class="invalid-feedback" data-sb-feedback="name:required">A name is required.</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <!-- Email address input-->
                                <input class="form-control" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email *" data-sb-validations="required,email" />
                                <div class="invalid-feedback" data-sb-feedback="email:required">An email is required.</div>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback" data-sb-feedback="email:email">Email is not valid.</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mb-md-0">
                                <!-- Phone number input-->
                                <input class="form-control" id="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Your Phone *" data-sb-validations="required" />
                                <div class="invalid-feedback" data-sb-feedback="phone:required">A phone number is required.</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group form-group-textarea mb-md-0">
                                <!-- Message input-->
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Your Message *" data-sb-validations="required"></textarea>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback" data-sb-feedback="message:required">A message is required.</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Submit success message-->
                    <div class="d-none" id="submitSuccessMessage">
                        <div class="text-center text-white mb-3">
                            <div class="fw-bolder">Form submission successful!</div>
                          
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Submit error message-->
                    <div class="d-none" id="submitErrorMessage"><div class="text-center text-danger mb-3">Error sending message!</div></div>
                    <!-- Submit Button-->
                    <div class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase disabled" id="submitButton" type="submit">Send Message</button></div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Footer-->
        <footer class="footer py-2">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row align-items-center text-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-7 text-lg-start">All Rights Reserved &copy; 2023</div>
     
                    <div class="col-lg-5 text-lg-end my-3">
                        <a class="link-dark text-decoration-none me-3" href="./attribution.html">Attribution</a>
                        <a class="link-dark text-decoration-none me-3" href="#!">Privacy Policy</a>
                        <a class="link-dark text-decoration-none" href="#!">Terms of Use</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
        <!-- Jquery-->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Popper-->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap-->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-fbbOQedDUMZZ5KreZpsbe1LCZPVmfTnH7ois6mU1QK+m14rQ1l2bGBq41eYeM/fS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>        
        <!-- Core theme JS-->
        <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

        <script src="https://cdn.startbootstrap.com/sb-forms-latest.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can i get the buttons to work?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you perhaps post the entire html file so that i can run it on my machine.

Comment: @RonMakila, i've edited the html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out. Just remove the `id="gallery"` from the `<section>` and put it into the `div` which is immediately after `<h2>`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <!--Gallery-->
<section class="page-section">
    <div class="container">
         <h2 class="section-heading text-uppercase text-center">Gallery</h2>
         <div id="gallery" class="carousel slide carousel-fade my-5" data-bs-ride="carousel">
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                   <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?random=1" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                   </div>
                   <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?random=2" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                   </div>
                   <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?random=3" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    </div>    
               </div>
               <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#gallery" data-bs-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
               </button>
               <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#gallery" data-bs-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
               </button>
          </div>
    </div>
</section>

       <!-- Jquery-->
       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
       <!-- Popper-->
       <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <!-- Bootstrap-->
       <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-fbbOQedDUMZZ5KreZpsbe1LCZPVmfTnH7ois6mU1QK+m14rQ1l2bGBq41eYeM/fS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>        
       <!-- Core theme JS-->

       
       <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It worked. I didn't even noticed it was in the section. Thanks a lot for your help.